# Template switch within render to response

Tags: python, django

What I'm trying to do is make a template switch within my view.
I want to be able to test 2 templates (test1.html & test2.html).

views.py

```
def testPage(request):
     .... yay code that does stuff ....
     return render_to_response(if 'test1' in url: 'signup/test1.html' else : 'signup/test2.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How would I go about recognizing the url within my view? Is this kind of thing possible? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You can access your url with request.path https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could setup your urls.py file to pass in a different argument. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions) here on it.

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
    url(r'^test/$', 'views.testPage', {'template_name': 'signup/test1.html'}),
    url(r'^$', 'views.testPage', {'template_name': 'signup/test2.html'}),
)

# views.py
def testPage(request, template_name):
    # code goes here
    return render_to_response(template_name, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use request.path or request.get_full_path for this. Your code modified:

```
def testPage(request):
 .... yay code that does stuff ....
 return render_to_response(if 'test1' in request.path: 'signup/test1.html' else : 'signup/test2.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```